# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple. How to solve?

Tags: python

I am trying to get this program to open and read two txt files I have made called cats.txt and dogs.txt

```
filenames = 'cats.txt', 'dogs.txt'
with open (filenames, encoding = 'utf8') as f_obj:
    contents = f_obj.read()
    print(contents)
```

But I keep getting this error message

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
```

But it works fine when I only do it with one of the txt files

I don't really know what the error message means and how can I solve it?

Comment: You seem to be attempting to open two files at the same time. What do you expect to happen at `f_obj.read()`? Should it read just one of the files, or both? If both, then in which order?

Comment: It means exactly what it says, that it is expecting you to pass a `str`, `bytes` or `os.PathLike` objects. You are passing it a tuple object

Comment: @quamrana I want it to print the content of the two files. The order is not important

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument to `open()` has to be one filename, not a tuple with multiple filenames in it.

If you want to read all the files, do it in a loop:

```
for filename in filenames:
    with open (filename, encoding = 'utf8') as f_obj:
        contents = f_obj.read()
        print(contents)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use a comma to separate two things in Python, you might* be creating a tuple.

```
>>> x=1
>>> type(x)
<class 'int'>
>>> x=1, 2
>>> type(x)
<class 'tuple'>
```

This is even true if you use a comma after *one thing*:

```
>>> x='hi',
>>> type(x)
<class 'tuple'>
```

Tuples are objects, like everything else, and a function expecting a string can't necessarily handle a tuple. But you can loop over a tuple and handle one string at a time.

```
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename) as f:
        ...
```

*(You *might* be creating a tuple, but you will certainly be creating an iterable of some kind. If you surround the expression with square or curly braces, you'll create a list or a set, but not necessarily a tuple.)